# How to remove nautilus without screwing up unity?

Tags: unity, nautilus, nemo

I recently installed Cinnamon on my Ubuntu 12.04.1 and I loved the interface of its file manager Nemo, which I guess is also based on Nautilus. But I prefer Nemo over Nautilus and I want to remove Nautilus completely and have Nemo as my defaut File Manager.

The problem however is that removing Nautilus requires me to remove ubuntu-desktop too. Is it possible somehow to retain Ubuntu Desktop and remove Nautilus?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to remove Nautilus - just set Nemo as default - see [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/10/install-nemo-with-unity-patches-and.html).

To install Nemo, open a terminal.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/nemo
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nemo nemo-filerolle
```

If you need to install extensions for Nemo (optional)

```
sudo apt-get install nemo-compare nemo-dropbox nemo-media-columns nemo-pastebin nemo-seahorse nemo-share
```

To use Nemo as default File Manager, you will need *dconf-tools*

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

To disable Nautilus from drawing the desktop item,

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false
```

To Set Nemo as the default file manager (replacing Nautilus),

```
xdg-mime default nemo.desktop inode/directory application/x-gnome-saved-search
```

If you have removed unity, you should be able to reinstall it.

Start your computer and login & open a terminal.

If you can't login, enter the `tty` with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>.

Then run:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-2d
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop-2d
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
sudo apt-get install xserver-xgl
sudo apt-get install emerald
sudo apt-get install compiz-fusion-plugins-extra
sudo apt-get install git compiz-plugins-extra
sudo apt-get install compiz-plugins-extra
sudo apt-get install unity
```

Then reboot - if in the `tty` just run:

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

Comment: Don't mind about the edit @GunJack - should of done it anyway - Would a better title for your new question be **Stuck with Intel GMA 3600** *(I think that is what it was about...)*

Comment: I asked that more than a dozen times. At least this one got some views. And with the edit, I was just trying to earn some points

Comment: Never mind... If your question had some more information, perhaps they would not of minded the title so much :-)

Comment: Some applications, like Zotero, do not respect xdg-mime. Only after removing Nautilus, they obeyed my preference of Dolphin.

Answer (score 3):

`ubuntu-desktop` is a package that doesn't contain any files but just depends on other packages (that's called a "metapackage"). Unity will still work if you remove this package.

Comment: I removed nautilus and now there is no Ubuntu or Ubuntu-2D in my login greeter.

Comment: What did it remove as dependencies?

Comment: It removes ubuntu-desktop

Comment: In 12.04 at least ``gnome-session`` depends on ``nautilus``. As Unity needs ``gnome-session`` this will also remove Unity (Cinnamon may be affected, too). But that is not caused by removing ``ubuntu-desktop``.